# ThinkingSphinx returns no results when in test mode in Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, thinking-sphinx, rails-3-upgrade

I'm on a project upgrading from Rails 2 -> 3. We are removing Ultrasphinx (which is not supported in Rails 3) and replacing it with ThinkingSphinx. One problem - the Cucumber tests for searching, which *used* to work, are failing as ThinkingSphinx is not indexing the files in test mode.

This is the relevant part of env.rb:

```
require 'cucumber/thinking_sphinx/external_world'
Cucumber::ThinkingSphinx::ExternalWorld.new
Cucumber::Rails::World.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

And here is the step (declared in my common_steps.rb file) that indexes my objects:

```
Given /^ThinkingSphinx is indexed$/ do
  puts "Indexing the new database objects"
  # Update all indexes
  ThinkingSphinx::Test.index
  sleep(0.25) # Wait for Sphinx to catch up
end
```

And this is what I have in my .feature file (after the model objects are created)

```
And ThinkingSphinx is indexed
```

This is the output of ThinkingSphinx when its run in test mode (this is WRONG, it should be finding documents but it is not)

```
Sphinx 0.9.9-release (r2117)
Copyright (c) 2001-2009, Andrew Aksyonoff

using config file 'C:/Users/PaulG/Programming/Projects/TechTV/config/test.sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'collection_core'...
collected 0 docs, 0.0 MB
total 0 docs, 0 bytes
total 0.027 sec, 0 bytes/sec, 0.00 docs/sec
distributed index 'collection' can not be directly indexed; skipping.
indexing index 'video_core'...
collected 0 docs, 0.0 MB
total 0 docs, 0 bytes
total 0.018 sec, 0 bytes/sec, 0.00 docs/sec
distributed index 'video' can not be directly indexed; skipping.
total 0 reads, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 8 writes, 0.000 sec, 0.1 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
rotating indices: succesfully sent SIGHUP to searchd (pid=4332).
```

In comparison, this is the output I get when I run

```
rake ts:index
```

To index the development environment:

```
Sphinx 0.9.9-release (r2117)
Copyright (c) 2001-2009, Andrew Aksyonoff

using config file 'C:/Users/PaulG/Programming/Projects/TechTV/config/development.sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'collection_core'...
collected 4 docs, 0.0 MB
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 4 docs, 39 bytes
total 0.031 sec, 1238 bytes/sec, 127.04 docs/sec
distributed index 'collection' can not be directly indexed; skipping.
indexing index 'video_core'...
collected 4 docs, 0.0 MB
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 4 docs, 62 bytes
total 0.023 sec, 2614 bytes/sec, 168.66 docs/sec
distributed index 'video' can not be directly indexed; skipping.
total 10 reads, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 20 writes, 0.001 sec, 0.1 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
rotating indices: succesfully sent SIGHUP to searchd (pid=5476).
```

Notice how its actually finding documents in my development database, but not my test database. The indexer is working in dev, but not test? I've spent 2 days on this, and am no closer to a solution. Any help would be overwhelmingly appreciated.

Comment: "We are removing Ultrasphinx [...] and replacing it with Ultrasphinx". Typo?

Comment: I edited your question to fix it - hope I guessed correctly )

Comment: Paul, can you share your scenario? Are you seeing the inserts being made in the test log? You're not overwriting the transactional fixtures setting elsewhere?

Comment: Yeap, Alexis, you were correct!

Comment: @pat Sure, my scenario is as follows:

(http://pastebin.com/iNbzFD40)

I've also included env.rb, and some output from the test.log file. I've checked for "use_transactional_fixtures" in my project but the only instance I found was in env.rb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out this morning, hopefully I can save someone else the troubles I experienced. Looks like **it wasn't a fault of Cucumber, but of DatabaseCleaner**.

I fixed this issue by changing this line in *env.rb*:

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
```

to

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to your problem! I've been scratching my head all morning (and sprinkling a whole bunch of print statements all over the place) to no avail. But your fix finally allowed my search results to show up on my Cucumber/Selenium page. Thanks again,
Larry

Comment: Glad I could help save you some time Larry! These things can be time drains... it's good to know I saved you some.